# Make a relationship to last element of a Field Collection

Tags: views, entities

I have a View with a relationship to Field Collection (with unlimited cardinality). I need this relationship to connect only to the last element (having the largest delta). How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot showing the relationship, to the last item of a Field Collection, which I need]

Comment: Just, FYI, the ability to [reference last delta in views](https://www.drupal.org/node/547732) (and last -n) has been requested before, and I don't think it is possible. Although the issue linked to is old and I suppose something might have changed. Interesting topic regardless. Good luck.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible with custom code but maybe not via the UI. The code may not be trivial though. If it is possible via code then it may also be possible to create a module that does allow users to do it via the UI.

Comment: Wow, there is a 5 year old issue for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show only the Field Collection item having the largest delta, you can use the [Field Collection Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module as your formatter (i.e., Views field-collection items) in your View (i.e., parent View). With this formatter you can select another View (i.e., sibling View) to display your field collection items (so you will get a View within a View).

In the parent View you simply specify in the 'Multiple field settings' to display only the last result (i.e., Display 1 value(s), starting from 0, reversed checked), see screenshot below:

[image: Views field-collection items formatter settings]

Note: in order to output the results in the order that is specified on your node, you have to set a relationship in the sibling View <view_name_for_field_collection> to 'Field collection item: Entity with the {Field Collection field}' and mark it as required. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1444798#comment-7423676) for the Field Collection Views for an extended explanation.

Let me know if you need any help with this.